# Route53 Resolver Cross Account Connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

We created Route53 Resolver in Account A which is shared with Account B and Account C.
There are Private Hosted Zones in Account B and Account C.

When we try to resolve Account C record from Account B, it doesn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to check the routes and firewall, post which it worked.